# Extracting polynomial from MuPAD to Matlab

Tags: matlab, export, polynomial-math, mupad

I have poly in MuPAD (one variable, several parameters). I want to extract it somehow to Matlab.

An example of poly in MuPAD:

```
poly((-7/(2*k^2))*X^2 + ((7*(b + k))/(2*k^2) + (7*(b + 2*k))/(2*k^2) + 4/k)*X + (- (b + k)*((7*(b + 2*k))/(2*k^2) + 4/k) + 1), [X])
```

I want to get it in Matlab:

```
x*((7*(b + k))/(2*k^2) + (7*(b + 2*k))/(2*k^2) + 4/k) - (7*x^2)/(2*k^2) - (b + k)*((7*(b + 2*k))/(2*k^2) + 4/k) + 1
```

Is there any handy way to do this? 
P.S. Matlab R2015a

Comment: To whoever marked this as unclear: This question is perfectly clear – perhaps you've never used MuPAD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you want to convert the MuPAD object of domain [`DOM_POLY`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/poly.html) to a general symbolic expression. You can use the [`expr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/expr.html) function for this. I'm assuming that you're already working from within Matlab here (from within MuPAD, it's just `expr(p1)`):

```
syms b k X
p1 = feval(symengine,'poly',(-7/(2*k^2))*X^2 + ((7*(b + k))/(2*k^2) + (7*(b + 2*k))/(2*k^2) + 4/k)*X + (- (b + k)*((7*(b + 2*k))/(2*k^2) + 4/k) + 1),'[X]')
p2 = feval(symengine,'expr',p1)
```

which returns

```
p2 =

X*((7*b + 7*k)/(2*k^2) + (7*b + 14*k)/(2*k^2) + 4/k) - (b + k)*((7*b + 14*k)/(2*k^2) + 4/k) - (7*X^2)/(2*k^2) + 1
```

You can also use [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert either form (`p1` or `p2` above) to a vectorized floating point function handle, e.g.:

```
f = matlabFunction(p1,'Vars',{b k X})
```

which returns

```
f = 

    @(b,k,X)-(b+k).*(1.0./k.^2.*(b.*7.0+k.*1.4e1).*(1.0./2.0)+4.0./k)+X.*(1.0./k.^2.*(b.*7.0+k.*7.0).*(1.0./2.0)+1.0./k.^2.*(b.*7.0+k.*1.4e1).*(1.0./2.0)+4.0./k)-X.^2.*1.0./k.^2.*(7.0./2.0)+1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`generate::MATLAB`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/generate-matlab.html) function to create the MATLAB code for any expression.
To print the function call (without quotes), you can use `print`.
A small example:

```
p := -7*X^2 + 8*X + 1
print(Unquoted, generate::MATLAB(p))
```

returns

```
t0 = X*8.0-X^2*7.0+1.0;
```

which is the correct MATLAB syntax for this function.